# regarding database security

Tags: mysql, security, prepared-statement

I am using prepared statements with mysqli(); to insert and retrieve data on my website also i used bind_param so i don't add variables directly into the query.I used strip_tags to clean any inputs what else should i look out for ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use strip_tags() on database input: use htmlentites() (or urlencode() where appropriate) on browser output.

Comment: This may seem like a silly q, but why shouldn't i use strip_tags ?

Comment: @andrei - `strip_tags` has nothing to do with database security; neither do `htmlentities` or `urlencode`. They are meant to solve XSS. `strip_tags` at input doesn't solve XSS. The right way to solve XSS is output encoding. See http://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Untrusted_Data for more information

Comment: "strip_tags at input doesn't solve XSS" i thought it did >< ; thanks for the article